# Can I add folders to the dock?

Tags: plank

I know that some docks support folders. Does Plank? If so, how can I add them?

Example image here:

[image]

Design from [here](http://bassultra.deviantart.com/art/Plank-Folders-387841239).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, Plank support folders for both apps and filesystem locations.

## For Filesystem Locations

1. Find the path/folder you want to create a shortcut to in Files.
2. Drag the folder to Plank.

## For Apps

1. Create a folder in `~/.local/share/applications`
2. Copy in the desired applications from `/usr/share/applications/`
3. Drag the folder to Plank.

[image]

Comment: does it also work for plank?? @crow

Comment: @Adityaultra - this IS about Plank, eOS's default dock

Comment: sorry docky @cipricus

Comment: But then you will have the entries under Applications doubled.
If you add the line 

**NoDisplay=true**

to the .desktop files in your folder, they will not be displayed under Applications, but in your folder in plank.

Comment: in fact you do not need a special location for the added folder, just not to require administrative access rights. I put mine in something like `~./My_launchers` and thus avoid the problem mentioned by @tim2611

Answer (score 4):

You can use Gnome-Pie as an alternative to grouping applications in the dock.

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:simonschneegans/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-pie
```

Video demonstration on [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/125339537).

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but an interesting alternative.