# Is it possible to get website shortcuts in the dock?

Tags: plank

Is it possible to include web shortcuts in the dock? [LauncherFolders](http://unity-folders.exceptionfound.com/) does that in Unity for Ubuntu. I like this possibility very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Midori, you can easily create an App from a webpage (a web app).

Click on the "Settings" button (The Cog symbol in the menu bar) from Midori and select "Applications".

From here, you can create a "New App" from the current page.

This App will appear in the Applications menu, and you can right-click and "Add to Dock"

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: [Webby](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Webby/)

Works very similiar to the Midori Feature

Answer (score 2):

- For [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?product=firefox-3.6.8&os=osx%E2%8C%A9=en-US):

  You can use [SaveLink](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/savelink/?src=search) add-on.

  *Usage*:

  Go to the web page you want to create shortcut, right click, click and select `SaveLink`

  [image: Imgur]

  Save the link to a particular folder and [place the folder in dock](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/250/can-i-add-folders-to-the-dock/252#252).

  **Note**: 
  Before that, make sure the file default application is a browser.
  For that, go to the folder, select the file --> right click --> open with --> other applications -->view applications --> select the default browser. (*This has to be done for first time*, from next time you can directly launch from dock )

  Alternatively you can use [*deskCut*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/deskcut/)  for this purpose, but its not working for me.

---

- For [*chrome*](https://www.google.com/chrome/):

  Go to system settings --> More tools --> *Add to desktop..*

  Now you will see it in app menu,like:

  [image: Imgur]

  Now **right click** on it, *add to dock*.

  [image: Imgur]

---

- For midori see [emjaySX answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3556/2708)

Answer (score 0):

google chrome has add to desktop feature in more tools.

Answer (score 0):

[Webby](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Webby/) is my favorite application for "sites as applications". However, I find that is is slow and unresponsive on my Acer C720. I also am unable to download linked files with it. That being said, websites that render with Webby, look much cleaner than Google Chrome or Firefox. I am not sure what it is - maybe the fonts, maybe the css engine, but webby's web engine is beautiful.

For sites that I think I might want to navigate a lot, download stuff, or are resource intensive, I will use Google Chrome Apps. Midori is also acceptable.