# How to drag folder to plank

Tags: plank

I followed the instructions given [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/252/4192) to add a folder / stack to my dock, but I can't seem to add the folder to the dock. It opens in the application it is dropped on, and no space is created for it.

Comment: in fact the location of the folder is not important as long as it does not need administrative rights to edit. - also avoid the location mentioned at that link, use one like `/home/username/my-launchers`

Comment: i can't drag the folder to the plank

Comment: be sure your target folder is NOT in a location that needs administrative rights to edit its content, then see my answer

Comment: please tell me if that worked for you, other solutions may be at hand like resetting Plank completely.

Comment: you could create a new question asking why this doesn't work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Plank build that comes with elementary OS Freya has

### certain features disabled by design.

If you have the official elementary OS build of Plank, then you will lack those features.

Consider this [answer by Daniel Foré](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1934/170) on the fact that the Plank build in elementary OS has certain features patched out. That is an answer on [a question about zoom](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1933/170): as you also lack zoom, as you mentioned in a comment, I think you are using the main elementary OS build of Plank.

**So, to get the full-featured Plank, you need to install the build from [Rico's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/docky)**.

I must have installed that already (see [my answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4733/170) under the linked question and Daniel's comment thereunder) since all these settings work in my case.

So, **there's nothing wrong with your Plank, it's the normal one in Freya, but you need Rico's build to get what you ask here**.

Just remove Plank, add that PPA, update, then install Plank again.

---

After that, you may change the settings:

Open `~/.config/plank/dock1/settings`

(if you just have one dock, otherwise you'll have different folders dock1, dock2 etc)

Or with `gedit` or other text editor:

`gedit ~/.config/plank/dock1/settings`

Be sure that you have `false` present like so:

```
#Whether to prevent drag'n'drop actions and lock items on the dock.
LockItems=false
```

Save and then see if drag&drop works.

To make the whole process more visible (the space needed created for the dropped item etc) maybe you should consider enabling also zoom:

```
#Whether the dock will zoom when hovered.
ZoomEnabled=true
```

With both `LockItems=false`  and `ZoomEnabled=true` it should look like so:

[image]

---

If it doesn't work you can also try this:

Each Plank item has a corresponding `.dockitem` file in `~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers`.

You could try creating your dockitem file there and see if that works, like so:

`gedit ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/name-of-your-directory.dockitem`

**replacing `name-of-you-directory` with the exact NAME of the target folder.**

Paste in there something like:

```
[PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///path/to/your/folder/name-of-your-directory
```

**Replace `file:///path/to/your/folder/name-of-your-directory` with the exact PATH of the target folder.**

and save

Tested it myself, it works for me.

---

Moving folder items **after** they are on the dock doesn't seem possible though, as long-clicking them to select and move them would just open their contents and options.

[image]

Comment: The first method does not work, the second does.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my dock. I cannot move the folder dockitem. I can move the other icons to move the folder to the right place, but I can't move the folder itself. Nor can I drag folders to the dock. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: does enabling zoom work? do you have the file ` ~/.config/plank/dock1/settings`?

Comment: you can disregard my last comment. i think not being able to move folders is normal. neither can i. long left click opens the content and options and cannot drag. that is the normal behaviour i think

Comment: @AnukulSangwan - **is zoom working for you?** --- if not, then you might want to take a look here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1933/170 There is a different build of Plank with enhanced features, if you don't have it already I think it deserves a try. It's what I have in fact.

Comment: no zoom in this one

Comment: @AnukulSangwan - that's the answer then! you need the build from [Rico's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/docky) to have all these settings available. I will add this info to the answer